# 2001 grand prix gt headlight has a tiny gray plug like thing on top of the lamp housing

Tags: headlight, pontiac

What is this tiny gray plug on the top of the headlight lamp housing

Comment: We can't see what you see. Take a picture, and add the picture into your question using the "edit" button below your question, followed by the "Moon and Mountains" button that will appear in the text entry box.